# Quarkus Unit Test isn't reading the properties in application.properties

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, quarkus

So I already have properties in my application-test.properties

```
%test.feature.retry.enabled=true
```

while in my application.properties:

```
%dev.feature.retry.enabled=true
```

then in my java code it looks like this:

```
@ConfigMapping(prefix = "feature")
public interface FeatureConfig {

    @WithName("retry.enabled")
    boolean isRetryEnabled();
}
```

then in service:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class GenerationService {

@Inject
    private SoaFeatureConfig featureConfig;

public Response mainMethod() {
if (featureConfig.isRetryEnabled()) {
...
}
```

I used @Mock in my test classes when I call the FeatureConfig but whenever I run my test classes, it is always false. Is there anything I forgot?

Comment: What do you mean "I used @Mock in my test classes when I call the FeatureConfig"? If the `FeatureConfig` is mocked then `isRetryEnabled()` will return false, unless instructed to do otherwise! If so, just instruct the mock to return true - e.g. with Mockito that would be as simple as: `when(mockFeatureConfig.isRetryEnabled()).thenReturn(true)`.

Comment: Profile aware config files (e.g. `application-test.properties`) do not need to be prefixed with profile prefix (e.g. `%test.`) At first please ensure that `application-test.properties` exists at the exact same location as the `application.properties`. After that in the `application-test.properties` just use `feature.retry.enabled` (without any prefix) as a config key.